# android : calling rxjava for a list of items

Tags: android, list, rx-java

I have a list of items, for each item i wan to do an async job and then update the UI. I am using rxjav for doing async task. How can i loop through the list and do this. I tried with Observable.FromArray thought it didnt work

```
 Observable.fromArray
```

Comment: Please provide more code. What didn't work? Have you tried searching for the keywords?

Answer (score 1):

`flatMap` is your answer. You will pass your list to `Observable`, in `flatMap` each item from the list will be passed so that you can do the async task. Finally, you can update the UI.

```
Observable.fromArray(yourArrayList)
.flatMap(item -> doAsyncTask)
.flatMap(item -> updateUI)
.subscribe();
```

You can refer to [marble diagram](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) on how `flatMap` works.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use .flatMap() for this. Flatmap will allow you to perform an action and emit an observable for each item. You can use this to perform async operations on each item in the list. The flat map operation can return items of the same type or another type.

Example:
Suppose you have a list of items of type Object1. You want to upload these to a REST API. The API will return the uploaded object in the response.

```
// Create observable
Observable<Object1> uploadObjects = Observable.fromIterable(objectsToUpload)
        .flatMap(object -> {
            // Calls uploadObject on each item in the list
            return MyAPI.uploadObject(object);
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // Performs the action on background thread
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()); // Returns result on UI thread

// Subscribe to observable
Disposable subscription = uploadObjects
        .subscribe(returnedObject -> {
            // Called for each returned object
            // Update UI here
        }, throwable -> {
            // Handle error here
        }, () -> {
            // Runs after all items completed
        });
```

Suppose `MyAPI.uploadObject()` takes an `Object1` as an argument but returns a different kind of object: type `Object2`. If this is the case, then the `uploadObjects` observable simply needs to be of type `Observable<Object2>`. Each `returnedObject` in the subscribe block with then be of type `Object2`.

Some nice examples from Dan Lew can be found [here](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/09/22/grokking-rxjava-part-2/).